# I can import module in python but cannot import the same module when using python command in gdb

Tags: python, gdb

I have a simple module called mini. It can be imported in either *python interactive interpreter* or a *python .py script*. The module is a `C` extension based so I want to debug it in `gdb` (version > 7). I learned that `gdb` has `python` command to interpret python command or script like:

```
(gdb) python import mini
```

However, it failed to import the module by saying:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: No module named mini
```

I guess it might be the environment setting with either my `gdb` setting or my `linux` searching path setting. What will be the possible reason of this problem? Thanks.

Comment: What directory is `mini` located in? If you do `python -c "import sys; print(sys.path)" and `gdb -q -ex "python print(sys.path)", does that directory appear in one list but not the other?

Comment: @MarkPlotnick Thank you. I ran python and gdb right at the path that mini lies in. When I do the python command as you stated, it shows the path information like this: ['', '/usr/lib64/python26.zip', ...]. But when I do the gdb command, it shows nothing. So does that mean the gdb was not configured well for me to use python inside it?

Comment: @MarkPlotnick Thank you. I may know the problem now. Follow your suggestions, I guess that when I use python interactive interpreter, the searching path in sys.path includes the current path where I launch python as well as mini lies. But when I use python in gdb, the current path is not in the sys.path. That may be the reason why it cannot find the module. Thank you so much!